# Why is Twitter converting an image I made with C and Python3, from PNG to JPEG?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, twitter, png

I am newish to programming and have been working on a little program that generates images of Julia sets and uploads them to my twitter account. The actual image is created in C as a PPM file, which a Python3 script then opens and saves as a PNG file, then uploads it to Twitter. This is fine, except that on Twitter the image is a JPEG and has a lot of artifacts.

I used ImageMagick's identify -verbose to compare my PNG image to another one that was on the internet. The main difference I found was that my image had "Type: Pallete" and the other PNG had "Type: TrueColorAlpha".

I have found other people online saying that by changing the transparency of one pixel, Twitter didn't convert the PNG to a JPEG, but I am having difficulty doing this.

The part of my C code that creates the PPM file is as follows:

```
FILE *f = fopen("julia.ppm", "wb);
fprintf(f, "P6\n %i 255\n", size, size); /*Size is an int defined previously*/

for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
   for(j=0; j<size; j++) {
      fputc(image[i][j],f);
      fputc(0, f);
      fputc(0, f);
   }
}
fclose(f);
```

"image" is a size*size array with values from 0 to 255 in each element.

My Python3 code that turns it into a PNG is as follows

```
import tweepy
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

#Twitter Info#

im = Image.open('julia.ppm')
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(1.5)
im.save('julia.png')

api.update_with_media('julia.png')
```

I would like to be able to upload the image to Twitter and have it stay as a PNG file if possible. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's upload tool seems now (May 2016) to always force a JPEG conversion.

You can still upload PNGs using the API and there's a tool to make that easy:

https://apigee.com/embed/console/twitter

1. Auth with your twitter account (near the top)
2. Choose the API method "update_profile_image.json"
3. Go to the 'Body' tab and scroll the top section down a bit till you find the image upload button.
4. Follow the sizing rules below (not the ones in the API tool - they seem out of date )
5. Hit "Send" :)

Current rules ( and docs of this endpoint ):

> Must be a valid GIF, JPG, or PNG image of less than 700 kilobytes in size. Images with width larger than 400 pixels will be scaled down. Animated GIFs will be converted to a static GIF of the first frame, removing the animation.

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_image